# Remove others' self-answered questions from unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, search, self-answer

Would it be possible to tag questions as self-answered or extract the answer from the question and mark it as accepted?

Comment: I added tags [meta-tag:search] and [meta-tag:advanced-search] since this could be implemented as a switch in the Search Fu. If you think I'm wrong, feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 4):

If a question has been solved either in the comments or by the OP editing the answer into their question, and is now lying around, feel free to post a proper answer. If you have moral questions about taking credit for other people's work, mark it as community wiki.

There's no guarantee that it'll get accepted (in fact, it seems to me that there's a rather low chance), but if it gets an upvote that'll remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Many self-answered questions are borderline quality questions with borderline not-an-answer answers. Some of them could in theory get closed (but what would it help to?) or reworded, but that all is quite a lot of work with (IMHO) little gain.

Comment: @yo' If you don't think the questions are worth spending time on, then don't spend time on them.  If you think they're worth spending time improving, then spend time improving them.  It's your decision to make.

Comment: @Servy Which means that the request by the OP is quite reasonable, so that he doesn't spend time on self-answered questions.

Comment: @yo' The fact that one person doesn't want to spend time on it doesn't mean nobody else does, or that nobody else should.  I see no reason why these questions should be treated any differently than any other.  If you personally don't want to spend the time, you don't have to, but that doesn't mean you should be actively inhibiting others who *do* want to help from helping.

Comment: @Servy I don't question this. I don't suggest the **default** unanswered list to be changed, but an **option to the Search Fu** could be added.

Comment: That's not what the question here is suggesting, so your statement that the OP's request is reasonable simply isn't true, as he isn't making that request.

Answer (score 2):

I write a query for *unanswered questions without self-answered* in [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com):

```
select TOP(50) 
  q.Id As [Post Link], 
  q.Tags
from 
  Posts q
  left join 
  Posts a on q.Id = a.ParentId
  
where
  q.PostTypeId = 1 and
  q.AcceptedAnswerId is null and
  0 = isnull((select max(ai.Score) 
              from Posts ai
              where ai.ParentId = q.Id), 0) and
  0 = isnull((select count(*)
              from Posts ai
              where ai.ParentId = q.Id 
                and ai.OwnerUserId = q.OwnerUserId), 0) and
  q.tags like '%##Tags##%'
group by
  q.Id,
  q.Tags,
  q.PostTypeId
```

For seeing a result-set for the top 50 unanswered questions without self-answered questions that involved tags of [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) in [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) you can check [this link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/307735/top-50-unanswered-questions-and-without-self-answered-question?Tags=mysql%25sql).